# Why won't the second GFCI outlet on a MWBC reset?

Tags: wiring

I have it set up so that the fountain it powers can have the Lights controlled by 1 Switch and the Pump by another. I used a 3 conductor w/GND for the cable. I used the Black for one GFI and the Red for the other one and these wires are controlled by separate switches. The white is my neutral and is jumped to each GFI and the GND is jumped to both. The 1st one work fine but the 2nd one will not set. What have I got wrong??

Comment: Some of the GFCIs in our house trip themselves when the power is turned on. Auto-test, perhaps. If that's the type you have on one of those GFCIs, then it can't be switched without a manual reset. Aside from that, be sure the loads don't share neutrals after the GFCIs.

Comment: How are you splitting the neutrals?  Did you remove the "Do Not Use - For Wizards Only" warning tape from the Load terminals of either GFCI?  Did you attach anything to Load terminals? If you unplug everything will the GFCI reset like normal?

Answer (score 3):

Given that the lights + pump do not exceed the capacity of a 15A circuit, you don't really need a *Multi-Wire Branch Circuit* here.

You could make do with a plain old "1 circuit powering two switches controlling two things" sort of deal, like is routinely done with bathroom light+fan, or ceiling fan+light.  This setup uses /3 cable, same stuff you have in the ground now.

And since they can both be on the same (leg of) a circuit, therefore, you don't need two GFCI devices.

This may be news to you, but GFCI is not an outlet. It is a zone of protection, and a GFCI device in one location can protect outlets elsewhere ("down the line") from the GFCI device.

- GFCIs as a rule do not like to be switched.
- GFCIs don't enjoy being outdoors and it ages them prematurely.
- In your current setup, the wiring to your GFCI receptacles is not protected at all, so if someone shoves a shovel into the cable, the GFCIs provide no protection.
- As such, the wire must be buried 24" deep or 18" if in conduit.  To qualify for 12" depth it must be GFCI protected *at the source* so a shovel hitting the cable trips the GFCI.  This requires using that "protected zone" feature.

We can solve all these problems by converting this from a MWBC to a fan+light style of wiring fed by 1 plain circuit, and actually fed from a GFCI before the switches.  Now the GFCI will be indoors, will not be switched, and will protect the cable run, both plain receptacles outside, and anything plugged into those outlets.

If you need to fit that into a 2-gang box, use a GFCI deadfront or receptacle (that fits in one gang), and a dual switch (that fits in the other gang).

Oh, and I hope you didn't use NM-B type cable for your outdoor/underground run.  That is not rated for outdoors/wet, and will actually fail in those conditions. The first sign of trouble is it will trip GFCIs feeding it, due to actual leakage out of the failing insulation.

Comment: So if I understand this I can remove the GFIs from the outlet and use standard outlets off of a single Power feed split between the 2 devices?

Comment: @Don I don't know how you wired it, so I couldn't say.   The outlets absolutely require GFCI protection one way or the other, but to put it simply it can come from a GFCI breaker.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what is going on in your setup. Pictures might help. But here is an alternative. Instead of using two switches + two GFCI/receptacle devices, use two GFCI/switch devices and two plain (but weather resistant) receptacles. That has a few advantages:

- Reset of GFCI is at the switch location, presumably a little more convenient than the receptacles.
- If your lighting and pump can be hard-wired (depends on the devices, but that is *often* the case, check the installation manuals) then you can eliminate the problem prone exposed receptacles altogether.
- GFCI not subject to frequent (every switch cycle...) power cycles, which shouldn't be a problem but can confuse some GFCI devices.

Something [like this Leviton from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-20-Amp-125-Volt-Combo-Self-Test-Blank-Face-GFCI-Outlet-White-R98-GFRBF-0KW/206001151#overlay):

[image]

The RESET button doubles as an ON button and the TEST button doubles as an OFF button. Actually that will work with almost any GFCI, but this is actually designed for frequent switching.

You wire up black to LINE hot of one, red to LINE hot of the other, white pigtailed to LINE neutral of both GFCI/switches. Then use standard 2-wire (plus ground) to connect from LOAD hot/neutral of each GFCI/switch to the lights and pump (or light receptacle and pump receptacle). Note that if the run from the switch to device/receptacle is outdoors then you have to use either cable that is rated for outdoor (wet location) use or appropriate wire inside conduit.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, but it would require replacing the presumably underground run of /3 cable with dual /2.

Comment: The presumably underground run of likely the wrong kind of cable and not deep enough besides...